# QueryDict doesn't split json data from PATCH request

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to update an object in my database using curl:

```
curl -X PATCH http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/search-archive/?id_search=6  --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"archive":true}'
```

but the data in QueryDict doesn't seem to split properly. Printing `request.data` shows:

```
<QueryDict: {"'{archive:true}'": ['']}>
```

My update view:

```
class SearchStopView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SearchSerializer
    def get_object(self,id_search):
        return Search.objects.get(id_search=id_search)

    def patch(self, request):
        print(request.data)

        id_search = self.request.query_params.get('id_search', None)
        search_object = self.get_object(id_search=id_search)
        serializer = SearchSerializer(search_object, data=request.data, partial=True) 

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and url code:

```
url(r'^api/search-archive/$', SearchStopView.as_view(), name='search-archive')
```

I've tried to change curl and url in many ways but nothing works...